# Headaches with radios in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 radios:

```
<input id="a_15_0" type="radio" value="abc" name="a_15"/>
<input id="a_15_1" type="radio" value="xyz" name="a_15"/>
```

Both are unselected. I have only the name of the radio, i.e `a_15`, but not the IDs.

**1)** How can I get the value of the selected option of this radio? E.g if the user clicked 'xyz', how can I get it? Right now I'm using:

```
var val=$('[name="a_15"]').val();
```

Which always gives abc even when xyz is selected.

**2)** How can I get xyz to be selected through javascript, without knowing the ID of the radio which says xyz? Doing:

$('[name="a_15"]').val('xyz');

Changes the value of both radios to xyz rather than selecting the one whose value had been xyz.

Do I need to use `document.myForm.a_15.value`? Would that work consistently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the val() in conjunction with the :checked selector?

```
$('[name="a_15"]:checked').val();
```

As for setting the selection based on the value, you may have to perform a multiple attribute tests?

```
$('[name="a_15"][value="xyz"]').get(0).checked = true;
```

Comment: I think it'll be a lot easier to use document.myForm.myRadio approach. Do you know if that would work both for getting the selected value of the radio and for selecting the value I want?

Comment: I'm not a fan of mixing jquery selectors and the old fashion DOM selectors.  If you app uses jquery then I would stick with this jQuery approach.  But that's my opinion.

Comment: Yes, and document.myForm didn't work anyways. Thanks a lot man, you're a life saver.

Comment: The document.myForm approach has always given me browser compatability complications.

Answer (score 2):

1)
try

```
var val = $('input[name=a_15]:checked').val();
```

[jQuery docs on checked pseudo-class](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checked)

2) the only solution I found is

```
$('input[name=a_15][value=xyz]').get(0).checked=true
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of selectors in [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors); id, class, etc..I believe this will do the job, not tested:

```
var val= $("input[name=a_15]:checked").val();
```

if you know the name of the form then this will definitely do it

```
var val= jQuery('#radio_form input:radio:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the correct code here:

[to run](http://jsbin.com/ebibi)

[to edit](http://jsbin.com/ebibi/edit)

the correct form is:

```
$("input[name='a_15']:checked").val();
```

as you can test using the links above